# Unable to connect to SQL Server on VPS remotely

Tags: sql-server, server, vps

I have a VPS, installed SQL Server and everything but the problem is that I can't access the database from outside my VPS.

I tried the following:

1. Enable port 1433 in firewall
2. Enable windows and server authentication in SQL Server
3. Enable TCP/IP
4. Make sure that SQL Browser is Running

When I connect using SQL Server authentication inside my VPS, it works fine, but from my PC I get this error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Now what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, your MS SQL server is not configured for Remote Access. Try following:

1) Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[image]

2) Click on **Protocols for SQLEXPRESS** from left hand side pane, from right hand side pane, double click on **TCP/IP**.This will open **TCP/IP properties**.

[image]

3) Under **TCP/IP properties** page, enter public IP address of SQL server under **IP address** field. Enter port number 1433 under port **TCP port** field.

4) Click on **Apply** and **OK**.

5) Restart the MS SQL Service.

6) Connect to MS SQL Server through SQL Server Management Studio as follows:

[image]

Comment: Already did that, here is how i connect to the Database using SQL Server
S+IP_Address+\SQLEXPRESS
Username
Password

Answer (score 0):

My response might be old though. Say you are still experiencing the same issue,

[image: Ensure that Protocol is set to Yes]

- Ensure that Protocol is set to Yes
- Then restart SQL Server and you
  should be fine.